# How to prevent Solution Explorer to automatically open selected item in editor (VS 2015)?

Tags: visual-studio

Please note I am not talking about "Track active item in Solution Explorer".
I like that, so when I am switching editor windows, Solution Explorer automatically tracks, and made selected the item in its tree. That's cool.

Instead I am asking about the reverse automatism: When I select an item in Solution Explorer (not double click, just select), it opens and activated in the editor using a single rightest tab, in the editor pane. (usual files are stacked from left tabs).

How can I prevent this automatic opening in VS 2015?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In VS 2013 it's under <kbd>Settings</kbd> - <kbd>Environment</kbd> - <kbd>Tabs and Windows</kbd> - <kbd>Preview Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Same in VS 2019